# Ionic 6 Ion-Select not working in Compiled Android Version

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic6

I am using Ionic 6 and capacitor 4 and
I have a simple ion-select as shown below

```
<ion-select class="selectStyle" v-model="settings.difficulty" interface="action-sheet" cancel-text="Cancel"
                    @ionChange="setDifficulty">
          <ion-select-option value="rand">Random</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="easy">Easy</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="medium">Medium</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="hard">Hard</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

It works fine on the web, but as a compiled android app the select isn't working. With not working I mean it's not clickable. So if i click on it, nothing happens. So the Overview of the Select Options wont show up.

Inspecting it with Chrome while running in an emulator, nothing is shown in the console.
I already imported IonSelect and IonSelectOption from ionic/vue. And same Code (except some CSS changes) worked with Capacitor 3.

Comment: define "not working"

Comment: what exactly is "not working"? can you make stackblitz. also try to change `@ionChange="setDifficulty"` to `@ionChange="setDifficulty($event)"`

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to specifiy this. With not working, i mean it is not clickable. So by clicking on the select, nothing happens. The Overview of the options wont show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it works now, updated capacitor only to version 4.0.
I now updated capacitor to 4.2. and also updated my ionic and ionic/vue packages from 6.0. to 6.2.
Seems like this was the problem.